# How to pass commands in a text file to an EXE running through the command line with batch?

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file with lots of commands in it and I want to sent those commands to a software called `thermocal`. It is a console application. I found the command below, but it doesn't work for me.

Do I need to put this .exe file in the same folder of the batch file to make it work or any thing else?

```
type somefile.txt | Thermocal.exe
```

Comment: Does the  application accept commands piped in from a text file? If not, doing so won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Batch scripts can be considered as a collection of lines you could also type in a command line prompt one after another. With respect to this it might be helpful for you, to play with cmd in order to get a feeling for what is happening.

About starting thermocal: Assuming thermocal is not part of [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) then the batch file either needs to change the current directory to the one with termocal.exe. Alternatively you might be able to call thermocal.exe with adding a path like C:\ProgramFiles\Thermocal\thermocal.exe . Play with cmd to find out, what works and what doesn't

When you are able to start thermocal from the command line prompt window, you can start experimenting with the call. You will probably end of with something like this in your command line window:
      C:\ProgramFiles\Thermocal> thermocal argument1 argument 2

If this works, you can start with batch programming :)

Assuming your arguments are stored in somefile.txt like this:

```
 argument1 argument 2
```

TYPE does nothing more than printing a file:

```
   TYPE somefile.txt
```

Now you need to use the result of the output as command line arguments:

```
   for /f %%i in ('type somefile.txt') do (thermocal.exe  %%i)
```